# Java concurrent:Is ReentrantLock a wrong design?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that **ReentrantLock** use **AbstractQueuedSynchronizer**(**AQS**) to implement **Lock**.
But the detail of the realization, I can not understand.

I know that **AQS** use volatile, **CAS** and spin for synchronizing. But, these actions only control the "state" member.

Although, **LockSupport.park** and **LockSupport.unpark** can synchronize the cacheline of the thread.
But if there is never contention, **LockSupport** methods will never be called.
Like this:
1.Thread A start and run

2.Thread B start and run

3.Thread A:

```
lock.lock();
try{
  //modify some shared members
  ....
}finally{
  lock.unlock();
}
```

4.Then Thread B:

```
lock.lock();
try{
  //read shared members
  ....
}finally{
  lock.unlock();
}
```

No contention, thread B does not call **LockSupport** methods.

**lock.lock()** only **CAS** "state" member, and **lock.unlock()** modify the volatile "state" to 0.

Why thread B can seen the modification of thread A about shared members?

Why **ReentrantLock** can use as "synchronized"?

I did not see any code like **fullFence** to synchronize memory.

Which code realize the synchronizing of the cacheline of the thread ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CAS operations define *happens-before* relations, so the Java memory model guarantees that memory modifications from a thread will be visible from the other one.

Comment: You mean that **CAS** will synchronize all cachelines of the thread, not only the **CAS** modified field? Is it?

Comment: no, threads and caches are implementation details of the JVM. Java (the language) defines a *Memory Model*: it gurantees that even if memory access or code execution are reordered, there can be no visibile effect